# scons - delete some of the built files after the compilation process

Tags: python, c++, swig, scons

I have a scons setup where I can choose to run SWIG and build a python module from c++.

this creates files such as

- x_wrap.cc
- x.lib
- x.obj

etc.

When all I want to have at the end of the process are theses files:

- _x.pyd
- x.py

Is there a way I can get scons to delete the unwanted files after the build process?

Comment: Can you possibly elaborate a bit more on why exactly you have to "cleanup"? SCons itself doesn't have the notion of "wanted" vs. "unwanted" files. So if you get the files you need out of the build process, why bothering about the side effects? It would also be helpful to see your basic setup in a MWE, which shows how you initialize and call the SWIG Builder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like using the "Delete" function as a Command, after the SharedLibrary line, allows me to delete the unwanted files.